# Vue.js: how to loop items in a list one item per each click of button

Tags: vuejs2

I need to render a list of items, one item at each click of a button.

The data is in store imported from JSON and has 3 levels of depth. 
I can loop through the 2 upper levels (division and group), but can't loop the lowest one (item). this means that I see all items within a group, and change group after the click.

When I console.log what item, group and division the code is reading , I can see that the item.id is increasing at each click. Infact, I need `item.lenght` number of clicks to pass to next group. Yet, all items are rendered together.

This is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxayg5r3/1/) with sample code.

In the example, I would like to see the word ‘something’ first, then after a click I should see ‘something else’, then ‘a thing’ and then ‘another thing’.

instead I see the 'something' group text all at the same time, and then the 'thing' group text.

Note that if in the computed items I do this (as I would have liked to do):

```
return this.groups.item[this.currentItem]
```

the fiddle stop working, and in my code I receive a 'Cannot read property 'id' of null.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with the .slice() method like this:

```
v-for=“item in filteredItems”
```

and

```
computed: {
    divisions () {
      return this.fullData.division[this.currentDivision]
    },
    groups () {
      return this.divisions.group[this.currentGroup]
    },
    items () {
        return this.groups.item
    },
    filteredItems: function () {
      if (this.items) {
        return this.items.slice(this.currentItem, this.currentItem + 1)
      }
    }
  }
```

But I remain curious on why I cannot use `item[this.currentItem]` and if there is a better way to list one item at a time without using .slice()